# Play Framework building select options including a no-op option

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm creating a search form with a select element which has "Any" as the first option. The rest of the options are widget ids and names.

The variable `myWidgets` is a list of three instances, the result I'm aiming for is along these lines:

```
<select id="widget" name="widget">
    <option value="-1">Any</option>
    <option value="10">Widget Ten</option>
    <option value="20">Widget Twenty</option>
    <option value="30">Widget Thirty</option>
<select>
```

Here's the Scala I'm using to generate it:

```
@helper.select(searchForm("widget"),
    Seq[(String, String)](("-1", "Any")) ++ 
    myWidgets.map(w => (new Tuple2[String, String](w.id.toString(), w.name)))
)
```

The second parameter of `select()` takes a `Seq[(String, String)]`. This works as shown, but it feels clunky. Is there a better (or more proper) way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So where is the data coming from? For selects I use MyEnum extends Enumeration, and my MyEnum class has a method like:

```
def toHtml: Vector[(String, String)] =  
("", "") +: super.values.toVector.map(m => (m.id.toString, m.toString))
```

To add a blank option on top of all selects.

Comment: I'm using Java Play, and the data is a Java `List<Widget>`. I see now that Play provides a `Tuple<A, B>` helper so I should be able to  put something together in Java that is similar. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @MattFlowers cool, ya try to keep it in Tuple2 from wherever the data is living (be it DB or Enum or whatever), and the select helper will eat it up